# Erro ao assinar xml nfse Curitba

Tags: java, xml, nfe

Pessoal estou com o seguinte erro :

```
Grave:   javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureException: javax.xml.crypto.URIReferenceException: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolverException: Cannot resolve element with ID 2
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
 Caused by: javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureException: javax.xml.crypto.URIReferenceException: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolverException: Cannot resolve element with ID 2
at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMReference.dereference(DOMReference.java:436)
at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMReference.digest(DOMReference.java:364)
at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignature.digestReference(DOMXMLSignature.java:496)
at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignature.sign(DOMXMLSignature.java:379)
at Controller.Assinador.assinaLoteRpsNFSe(Assinador.java:161)
at Controller.Assinador.assinaNFSe(Assinador.java:205)
at Controller.Assinador.assinaXML(Assinador.java:193)
at Controller.solicitacaoBean.xml(solicitacaoBean.java:686)
at Controller.solicitacaoBean.gravaFaturamento(solicitacaoBean.java:366)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:332)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:537)
at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:283)
at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
... 36 more
Caused by: javax.xml.crypto.URIReferenceException: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolverException: Cannot resolve element with ID 2
at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMURIDereferencer.dereference(DOMURIDereferencer.java:121)
at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMReference.dereference(DOMReference.java:430)
... 55 more
Caused by: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolverException: Cannot resolve element with ID 2
at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.resolver.implementations.ResolverFragment.engineResolveURI(ResolverFragment.java:89)
at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolver.resolve(ResourceResolver.java:313)
at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolver.resolve(ResourceResolver.java:298)
at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMURIDereferencer.dereference(DOMURIDereferencer.java:114)
... 56 more
```

Segue meu xml onde esta tentando assianr

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EnviarLoteRpsEnvio xsi:schemaLocation="http://isscuritiba.curitiba.pr.gov.br/iss/nfse.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://isscuritiba.curitiba.pr.gov.br/iss/nfse.xsd">
<LoteRps id="2" xmlns="">
<NumeroLote>2</NumeroLote>
<Cnpj>06994660000111</Cnpj>
<InscricaoMunicipal>04890151</InscricaoMunicipal>
<QuantidadeRps>1</QuantidadeRps>
<ListaRps>
<Rps>
<InfRps>
<IdentificacaoRps>
<Numero>201612051</Numero>
<Serie>F</Serie>
<Tipo>1</Tipo>
</IdentificacaoRps>
<DataEmissao>2016-12-05T10:46:21</DataEmissao>
<NaturezaOperacao>1</NaturezaOperacao>
<RegimeEspecialTributacao>1</RegimeEspecialTributacao>
<OpitanteSimplesNacional>1</OpitanteSimplesNacional>
<IncentivadorCultural>2</IncentivadorCultural>
<Status>1</Status>
<Servico>
<Valores>
<ValorServicos>250.0</ValorServicos>
<ValorDeducoes>0.0</ValorDeducoes>
<ValorPis>25.0</ValorPis>
<ValorCofins>25.0</ValorCofins>
<ValorInss>0.0</ValorInss>
<ValorIr>25.0</ValorIr>
<ValorCsll>25.0</ValorCsll>
<IssRetido>2</IssRetido>
<ValorIss>25.0</ValorIss>
<ValorIssRetido>0.0</ValorIssRetido>
<OutrasRetencoes>0.0</OutrasRetencoes>
<BaseCalculo>250.0</BaseCalculo>
<Aliquota>0.0</Aliquota>
<ValorLiquidoNfse>0.0</ValorLiquidoNfse>
<DescontoIncondicionado>0.0</DescontoIncondicionado>
<DescontoCondicionado>0.0</DescontoCondicionado>
</Valores>
<ItemListaServico>0.0</ItemListaServico>
<Descriminacao>MANUTENCAOO VEICULAR - TOTAL 250.0 SOLICITACAO null BANCO DO BRASIL AGENCIA 0756-0CONTACORRENTE :54582-1 </Descriminacao>
<CodigoMunicipio>4106902</CodigoMunicipio>
</Servico>
<Prestador>
<Cnpj>06994660000111</Cnpj>
<InscricaoMunicipal>04890151</InscricaoMunicipal>
</Prestador>
<Tomador>
<IdentificacaoTomador>
<CpfCnpj>
<Cnpj>03141166000116</Cnpj>
</CpfCnpj>
</IdentificacaoTomador>
<RazaoSocial>Tribunal Regional do Trabalho da 9ª Região</RazaoSocial>
<Endereco>
<Entedeco>Al. Dr. Carlos de Carvalho</Entedeco>
<Numero>528</Numero>
<Bairro>Centro</Bairro>
<CodigoMuniciopio>4106902</CodigoMuniciopio>
<Uf>PR</Uf>
<Cep>80430180</Cep>
</Endereco>
<Contato>
<Telefone>4133107770</Telefone>
<Email>augustosilva@trt9.jus.br</Email>
</Contato>
</Tomador>
</InfRps>
</Rps>
</ListaRps>
</LoteRps>
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<SignedInfo xmlns="">
<CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
<Reference URI="#2">
<Transforms>
<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
</Transforms>
<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<DigestValue/>
</Reference>
</SignedInfo>
<SignatureValue xmlns=""/>
<KeyInfo xmlns="">
<X509Data>
<X509Certificate/>
</X509Data>
</KeyInfo>
</Signature>
</EnviarLoteRpsEnvio>
```

Segue minha classe de assinar:

```
    public void assinaLoteRpsNFSe(String tipo, XMLSignatureFactory fac,
        ArrayList<Transform> transformList, PrivateKey privateKey,
        KeyInfo ki, Document document, int indexNFe) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, MarshalException, XMLSignatureException, javax.xml.crypto.MarshalException {
    if (tipo.equals(Assinador.EnviarLoteRpsEnvio)) {
        this.elements = this.document.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("LoteRps");
    }
    if (tipo.equals(Assinador.RPS)) {
        this.elements = this.document.getElementsByTagName("InfRps");
    }

    this.el = (org.w3c.dom.Element) this.elements.item(indexNFe);

    String id = el.getAttribute("id");
    this.ref = fac.newReference("#" + id,
            fac.newDigestMethod(DigestMethod.SHA1, null), transformList,
            null, null);
    this.si = fac.newSignedInfo(fac.newCanonicalizationMethod(
            CanonicalizationMethod.INCLUSIVE,
            (C14NMethodParameterSpec) null), fac
            .newSignatureMethod(SignatureMethod.RSA_SHA1, null),
            Collections.singletonList(ref));
    this.signature = fac.newXMLSignature(si, ki);
    this.dsc = new DOMSignContext(privateKey,
            document.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName(tipo).item(indexNFe));
    this.signature.sign(this.dsc);
}
```

pelo que eu vi esta dando erro na ultima linha `this.signature.sign(this.dsc);`

Answer (score 1):

O layout não está correto, verifiquei o XSD da NFSe e não existe o atributo id na tag de lote

> ```
> <LoteRps id="2" xmlns="">
> ```

Sugiro dar uma olha nos exemplos, no manual de utilização possui um link para download dos arquivos de exemplo.

http://isscuritiba.curitiba.pr.gov.br/portalNfse/manuais.aspx

Comment: Amigo a assinatura eu consegui resolver , agora o problema é EnviarLoteRpsEnvio , vc tem algum exemplo de como fazer?

Comment: No manual de utilização tem um link para download de um arquivo .zip, como mencionei acima, com exemplos de todos os casos que vai precisar. Mas se mesmo assim o erro persistir, peço que faça uma nova pergunta já que o contexto é outro, assim respeitamos as normas do stack.